# Parasitic oscillation in BJT booster stage of voltage controlled current source

Tags: mosfet, bjt, current-source, oscillation

I have constructed a voltage controlled current source for driving high power LEDs. In essence, it is a power N-channel FET in series with the LED whose gate is driven in reference to a 1 Ohm low-side sense resistor. I have included a BJT booster stage inside this feedback loop to enable high-frequency modulation of the gate voltage and therefore load current. I'm targeting ~100ns 1A turn on times. The circuit is shown here for reference:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIyvnl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The feedback loop is stable and operating as desired. However, there seems to be a parasitic oscillation in the emitter follower formed by Q1 within the BJT booster stage. This results in an ~20 mA ripple riding on top of the LED current for DC reference signals. The oscillation is seen riding on the of the LED current but is not present in the reference voltage.

Scope trace showing reference voltage (yellow) and LED current pulse (blue, 1A/V) with the small oscillation riding on it:
[image: 1 Amp LED pulse]

Same as last image with 1A offset and zoomed:
[image: Zoomed version with 1A offset]

I believe this a local, parasitic oscillation rather than instabilities in the feedback loop because:

1. If I break the feedback loop and apply DC voltages to the base input node (labeled "A" in the circuit diagram), the oscillation persists.
2. Poking the base of Q2 (labelled "B" in the diagram) with a pair of metal forceps while my hand is also touching a ground point removes the oscillation for the first part of the pulse. The oscillation seems to go away at the start of the current pulse, but it quickly returns 10 usec or so into the pulse. I have pictures of this but I'm not allowed to show them because my rep is too low.
3. Increasing the value of the compensation capacitor (C6) does not affect the frequency of the oscillation.

I've tried playing with the values of base stoppers (R1, R2) adding capacitance between various terminals of Q1 and Q2 and I have not found a solution that totally gets rid of this oscillation. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**EDIT** Fixed schematic to include power supply decoupling elements.

**EDIT** Fixed schematic to include MAX4564 analog switch series resistance.

Comment: The first thing I would do is remove C5. The second thing I would do is add base resistors (10-100 ohm) to Q3 and Q4. The third thing I would do is increase R7 and R8. What I am actually going to do however is sleep. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I will try the base stoppers at Q3,4 but I'm skeptical due to the fact that poking node B in the circuit with hand-held metal forceps seems to have the largest effect. I put R7, R8 in the circuit to prevent thermal run away by reducing the gain of Q3,4 with increases output current. I didn't know they could also have an effect on the circuit stability. Can you expand on that part?

Comment: Try better power rail decoupling.

Comment: @Andyaka I've left out a few small ceramic and bulk decoupling capacitors out of the diagram for the sake of simplicity. Adding more e.g. C1,2 directly to the collectors of Q1, Q2 was the first thing I tried. Where do you think are some other critical nodes where I might try adding them?

Comment: DO NOT leave components out - this wastes people's time.

Comment: @Andyaka Very sorry, I've added them. Two 10uF 1206 X7R ceramics at the power rails along with a couple bulk electrolytics. I guess to be complete, I should mention that this circuit's rails are provided by two linear regulators with their own decoupling elements. Is it worth it to include those too?

Comment: Have tried adding the resistor in series with the opamp inverting input?

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes, I have. I was reading up on compensation techniques so I might have something slightly informative to report in response to your answer below. The short story is that it actually seemed to make things worse. The circuit now rings even during the "off" phase, when gate voltage is dropped below threshold.

Comment: @jonnew - Unexpected.  The other thing that looks unusual is why C5 is there.  That will hurt the phase response of the amplifier.  I suggest removing it.

Comment: @jonnew R7 and R8 will reduce the gain of Q3,Q4 (as you said), which can in turn reduce the susceptibility to oscillation. Similarly, base stoppers on Q3,4 will reduce the gain at high frequencies by reducing the available Vbe at high frequencies - remember that at high frequencies the hFE is low so more base current will be required.

Comment: @jonnew Your load (the MOSFET gate) is almost purely reactive. If it is a TO220 package it probably has at least 10nH of inductunce in the gate in series with whatever the gate capacitance is. This is a recepie for instability. Try putting a zobel network on the output (MOSFET gate to GND as close to R7 and R8 as possible) .2.2R in series with 10nF would be my starting point from experience, but it will be a case of "suck it and see".

Comment: @Matthew I've worked my way through all your suggestions. Thanks for that. Unfortunately none of them worked for my issue. The only noticeable effect was the Zobel Network which increased overshoot in the rising portion of the square wave considerably. Even in that case though, the 20 MHz oscillation rode along the waveform the whole way indicating they really are two different issues. I did find something that worked -- I simply put a 1 kOhm resistor from the output of the op-amp (Node A) to ground. That solved the oscillation. I don't know why though. It would be great to understand.

Comment: @jonnew My best guess would be: Rail to rail op-amp has output topology of common emitter and output stage looks like a current source with a control loop. You don't have direct DC feedback as in the datasheet, but instead you have something like 100k load. High impedance load on a current source tends to be unstable.

Answer (score 3):

You need a resistor between the sense resistor and the inverting input of the opamp.

Although have correctly put a feedback cap for the opamp the pole is determined by the feed resistor and the capacitor - you are feeding it with 1 ohm!

I would try a few kilohm series resistor.

Comment: I tried to do this with several values of series resistor. Each value actually made the situation worse. It certainly limited the loop bandwidth as we would expect, but the parasitic ~20 MHz oscillation was still present and actually spread to the "off" portion of the waveform. After a lot of consideration, I finally realized I made a mistake on my schematic. There is analog switch (MAX4564) in the feedback path that is introducing ~40 Ohms of series resistance before the inverting input of the amplifier. I neglected to include this resistance in my schematic, which I've now updated.

Comment: I did find a way to solve the problem, but I don't understand it: I simply put a 1 kOhm resistor from the output of the op-amp (Node A) to ground. That solved the oscillation. You can still see a tiny bit of it (one cycle or so) right after the rising edge, but then it dies away in the next cycle. Any how this might be working?

Comment: The resistance between the current shunt and the op-amp input is necessary. It's not a fix for the oscillation, it's a fix that ensures that the circuit will be robust :)

Answer (score 2):

At high frequencies, the output impedance of the opamp OA2 goes up, and it is inductive. Beyond the transistor corner frequency f<sub>β</sub> (which is approximately f<sub>t</sub>/β), the inductive impedance on the base of transistor Q1 is transformed by the transistor into a negative impedance on the emitter of Q1. The emitter of Q1 has a high impedance load. When the overall impedance at the Q1 emitter node goes negative, the circuit oscillates.

The fix works because the resistor is in parallel with the inductive output of the opamp. This makes the overall impedance at this node less inductive. It may also be changing the operating point of the opamp such that the output impedance goes down. If the fix still works when a capacitor is added in series with the load resistor, then the fix is not due to changing the opamp operating point. This capacitor may be useful by decreasing the DC load current on the opamp, and also potentially allowing a lower value to be used. The capacitor can be chosen to only present this load at high frequencies, where the output impedance is inductive.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I would like to go about testing this answer.

1. If I place a cap after the 1k resistor and it still works (meaning resistor will only have an AC effect, we can be pretty sure the cause of the oscillation is due to the inductive output impedance of the OA at high frequencies.

Comment: 2. If this does work, and I understand the last part of your answer "lower value" refers to the load resistor that is in parallel with the inductive output of the opamp. If I place a cap in series with this resistor then I can potentially drop the value of the resistor substantially without worrying about DC load in the opamp, right?

Comment: Yes, the capacitor will help by allowing you to use a smaller resistor without drawing more DC current. There will still be the AC load current to deal with. Even with the capacitor, if the resistor is very small (for example 10 Ohms), it will decrease the gain of the opamp by shorting the output, which you probably don't want.